# Remove underline from hyperlinks in tag filter emails

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design, email, tag-filters

Maybe I'm just being OCD, but can the underlining of the filter emails be removed?

It is a lot more readable and looks a lot better to me without underlining, and it's not like it's difficult to tell that it's a link (these are after all people who have used a site on the Stack Exchange network before, and are thus used to similar functionality).

I know it's links and links can generally be underlined, but titles should not be. We don't underline question titles on any site I can think of, do we? Unless you mouse-over, but that's not enough justification to underline *all of them* in the emails just because mouse-over events don't work in emails (or do they?).

Or is there a specific reason (other than the one mentioned above) for underlining it in emails?

Which do you think looks better?

[image]

It might be nice to have a place where all formatting concerns (if any others) with these emails are discussed (and voted on), should this be the place? Or should these be individual questions?

Also, if possible, I think I'd like to have it look a lot more like the Stack Overflow questions page:

- Display votes
- Display answers
- Display tags more clearly
- Display asker reputation (?)
- Display the site the question is on more clearly (how?)

The above (votes and answers) can be considered at the time of sending, I realize this can be misleading, since you may only read the e-mail a lot later, but I think something's better than nothing.

But, first and foremost, I'd just like to have the underlining removed.

Comment: I think issues/concerns regarding formatting should have individual discussions/threads.

Comment: @CDY My only problem with that is that most of these can probably fit into 1 line, which seems a bit sparse for a question. Although you can buff it up with an elaboration and some screenshots (like I did), but the essence is still just 1 line. Anyway, that's just my opinion, not sure what the preferred way is for such things, I have seen stuff vaguely similar to my suggestion happen here.

Comment: For usability, color shouldn't be the only indicator.